# Getting this error in production build, but not in development... no clue how to track it down

Tags: reactjs

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

It runs fine locally, but on my production build I get that error.

In production I see this:

```
Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Pu (react-dom.production.min.js:275)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:148
    at Ra (react-dom.production.min.js:173)
    at vl (react-dom.production.min.js:268)
    at cu (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at lu (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
    at Zl (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:123
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
    at Vo (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
r   @   VM31 react_devtools_backend.js:6
el  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
n.callback  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
di  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
il  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
pu  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
Vo  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
du  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
Zl  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
(anonymous) @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
t.unstable_runWithPriority  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
Vo  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
qo  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
Qo  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
L   @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
Xt  @   2.3b321ef3.chunk.js:2
```

I clicked the URL and it showed me the actual error message.

So I have no idea where this error is occurring in my code, basically, as it doesn't occur in development.

Comment: which part of the code did this error occer?

Comment: Somewhere is expected a Component and instead you provided undefined. Try to 1 use `React.StrictMode` and 2 to run your build in production mode but without minifying your code... this should help you identify the issue

Comment: ^^What he said, try building to production without minifying